# Create DDP Server using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, ddp

Due to restrictions on node.js versions, recent versions of Meteor cannot be used on the system. A DDP server has to be created using regular node.js instead, which a Meteor setup will connect to.

DDP client can be created in node.js using [node-ddp-client](https://github.com/oortcloud/node-ddp-client), but how can we create a DDP server?

Comment: I'm curious - do you have any new informations on this? I look into ways to implement a reactive datasource that is not a mongodb or another database.

Comment: What restrictions? I'm interested as I've just started learning meteor

Answer (score 4):

It might be too late to answer this and this might not be a good answer anyway. It's not an easy task, we need to manage sessions, users, methods, publications... As a reference for a brave developer :)

- We need [EJSON](https://github.com/primus/EJSON) or some other implementation to serialize and deserialize messages between client and server.
- We need a socket server ([sockjs](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node) would be a good choice since meteor is using it too.)
- We need to implement [DDP specification](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/ddp/DDP.md)

Comment: Thanks for your input! Guess we can wait for someone awesome to write an npm package for it

Answer (score 1):

I've found https://www.npmjs.com/package/ddp-server-reactive and https://www.npmjs.com/package/ddp-server which both seem to do the job